# Converting string to datetime php not returning as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

In my application, I'm getting separated date and time values from a form and then I concatenate them to pass it to a method which converts to a `DateTime` object in php. The problem is that when I call the function **DateTime::createFromFormat**, it returns a zero giving an error right after when I try to insert as a `datetime` mysql datatype. The code is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, array(
        'titulo' => 'required|max:255',
        'descr' => 'required|max:255',
        'cidade' => 'required|max:255',
        'rua' => 'required|max:255',
        'bairro' => 'required|max:255',
        'nro' => 'required|numeric'
    ));

    $dataInic = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', 
            $request->input('diaInic') . "-" .
            $request->input('mesInic') . "-" .
            $request->input('anoInic') . " " .
            $request->input('horaInic') . "-" .
            "0" . $request->input('minutoInic') . "-"
            );
    //$dataInicInput = $dataInic->format('Y-m-d H:i');

    $dataFim = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', 
            $request->input('diaFinal') . "-" .
            $request->input('mesFinal') . "-" .
            $request->input('anoFinal') . " " .
            $request->input('horaFinal') . "-".
            $request->input('minutoFinal') . "-"
            );
    //$dataFimInput = $dataFim->format('Y-m-d H:i');

    //creates the model to insert in mysql db
    $event = new Event;

    $event->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $event->descr = $request->descr;
    $event->cidade = $request->cidade;
    $event->rua = $request->rua;
    $event->bairro = $request->bairro;
    $event->nro = $request->nro;
    $event->horarioinic = $dataInic;
    $event->horariofim = $dataFim;

    $event->save(); 

    Session::flash('success','O evento foi salvo com sucesso!');

    return redirect()->route('pages.agenda');
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) the format `d-m-Y H:i` seems to be right since the concatenations of the inputs is generating strings like: `22-12-2016 15-30` and `1-2-2016 2-5`.

Comment: The correct format for dates in MySQL is the ISO 8601 format:  YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Laravel, you can use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for this:

```
Carbon::parse($dateTimeString);
```